# What are the events generated when you open a TitleWindow using PopUpManager.addPopUp()?

Tags: apache-flex, popupwindow

Basically, I'm trying to open/close a TitleWindow using PopUpManager.addPopUp() and PopUpManager.removePopUp() while reusing the same TitleWindow instance. I noticed that the creationComplete() is only called once for TitleWindow even if I open it several times and was wondering what events I should listen to for the succeeding popup loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`creationComplete` (`FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE`) is fired only when the component is created; this happens only once since you are reusing the same component. Listen to `added` (`Event.ADDED`) or `addedToStage` (`Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`) events if you want to do something every time a display object is displayed.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed added() was being called, but it was being invoked several times while the popup is showing. I only called addPopUp once though. 

It might be worth mentioning that I also have a DataGrid whose data is refreshed every 10 seconds by a Timer but I don't think that should cause the add() event to be called more than once. 

I'll try the addedToStage() event and see how it works.

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to verify the addedToStage event as we already modified our approach (we just instantiated a new TitleWindow every time we opened a popup to make things simpler). 

But I'll accept this answer anyway. Thanks Amarghosh.

Comment: If you are instantiating new `TitleWindow` every time, you can use either `creationComplete` or `addedToStage`.

Comment: Thanks I'm currently using creationComplete. ;)